# Is there a way to set a hotkey for pressing on certain parts of the screen?

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys, gaming

I know this isn't something too useful for everyone 
but i want to hook up a hotkey for parts of the screen when I play a phone vision of LOL(League Of Legends) so that I don't need to individually click on each ability, and just press the hotkey to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/).

The following script will click on a point when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>
is typed :

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen    ; Coordinates are relative to the desktop (entire screen)
^a:: Click, 44, 55          ; Ctrl-A clicks left mouse button at coordinates 44, 55
```